# How not to require the import of scala.language.relectiveCalls

Tags: scala, scalatest

I subclassed `org.scalatest.FlatSpec` to add practical tooling to FlatTest. But anywhere I use this subclass, I have to import `scala.language.reflectiveClass` otherwise I get

```
reflective access of structural type member method test should be enabled 
by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
```

The method `test` in question is the equivalent to `should` in standard FlatSpec:

```
it should "do some stuff" in { ...}
```

Why is it not necessary to import reflectiveCalls to use flatSpec `should` but is necessary for my `test` method, and how can I avoid that?

Comment: Could you please show us `test` method and how you use it? According to warning you have a `new {...}` call in it.

Comment: Well you answered the question in a way. I cannot gives the whole code (private and boring anyway), but I do use `new { ... }` : I defined `we` which act as `it` (to not override `it`, which gives `we test "..." in {}` ) and I did not bother define a proper class:  `val we = new{ ... }`. That was not clean code.

Comment: can you put it in an answer ?

Comment: yep, no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this warning is that you have structural type reference or `new {...}` call somewhere in your `test` method.

Unfortunately there is no way to turn off that warning other than by explicit `scala.language.reflectiveClass` import or rewriting your code.